# How to call post method using Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two ActionResults() method  [httpget] and [httppost]
 I am posting the values with Ajax , but not calling httpPostmethod 
I am using MVC 4.0 and C#, post method is not calling.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.CrsCatgory = new SelectList(objIns.CoursCatgry(), "CC_ID", "Course_Catgory");

    var result = objstu.studentsearch();

    return View(result);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string clas, string Demo, string CoursesName, string LocationName, string CourseCatagory, string fromdate, string todte)
{
    ViewBag.CrsCatgory = new SelectList(objIns.CoursCatgry(), "CC_ID", "Course_Catgory");

    var result = objstu.studentsearch(clas, Demo, CoursesName, LocationName, CourseCatagory, fromdate, todte);

    return View(result);
}
```

I am writing  Ajax Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Loadlogos();
    LoadAllCoureses()

    $("#Searchtype").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var clas = $("#CheckClS").val();
        var Demo = $("#CheckDemo").val();
        var CoursesName = $("#Courselist").val();
        var LocationName = $("#autofillLocation").val();
        var CourseCatagory = $("#cat_id  option:selected").val();
        var fromdate = $("#frmdate").val();   
        var todate = $("#Todates").val();

        var url = "/Artists/Details?NestId=" + NestId;

        window.location.href = url;

        $.ajax({
            url: "Index",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{ 'clas': '" + clas + "','Demo': '" + Demo + "','CoursesName': '" + CoursesName + "','LocationName':'" + LocationName + "','CourseCatagory': '" + CourseCatagory + "','fromdate': '" + fromdate + "','todte': '" + todate + "'}",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           }
        });
});
```

Comment: `"post method is not calling"` - Then what *is* happening?  Is a different method being invoked?  Is the AJAX request being made at all?  What is the server's response?

Comment: url: "IndexPost" ?

Comment: You method is name `Index`, not `IndexPost` - `url: '@Url.Action("Index")',`

Comment: hi@stephen i tryed like that also but am anit geeting